# Why do I have the message max_wal_size suddenly appearing in my postgres logs?

Tags: postgresql

I've been running a bash script for 3 days and today I got this message popping up:

```
2023-01-16 12:29:26.440 UTC [27] LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (27 seconds apart)
2023-01-16 12:29:26.440 UTC [27] HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "max_wal_size".
2023-01-16 12:29:51.155 UTC [27] LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (25 seconds apart)
2023-01-16 12:29:51.155 UTC [27] HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "max_wal_size".
2023-01-16 12:30:17.429 UTC [27] LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (26 seconds apart)
2023-01-16 12:30:17.429 UTC [27] HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "max_wal_size".
```

I don't understand why this message appears overnight.

Indeed I perform a COPY of 63,000,000 csv lines.

Comment: Because you had lots of data modifications at that time (perhaps an autovacuum?).

Answer (score 1):

The database keeps transaction logs in the pg_wal directory.

The max size of this directory is defined by the config setting `max_wal_size`.

The database will on schedule flush those transactions logs. It does this through a mechanism known as checkpointing.

The database spreads the cost of flushing those over time to reduce resource contention. This is determined by the config setting `checkpoint_timeout` and `checkpoint_completion_target`.

If your database is transactionally heavy or has heavy periods it can produce transactions log at a rate faster than it can checkpoint.

This causes the flushes to happen more frequently which can cause resources to be consumed unnecessarily.

To help prevent this you can increase the size allowed in this directory by adjusting the `max_wal_size` setting.